# I need CTRL+BREAK remoting into a Windows computer from an android OS tablet

Tags: remote-desktop

I want to be able to remote into my computer for work from an android based tablet.  I have a keyboard for the tablet with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> & <kbd>BREAK</kbd> keys.  I need to be able to send a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>BREAK</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and separately <kbd>F7</kbd> into the computer that I am remoting into.  I have tried ***Remote RDP Lite*** and ***PocketCloud** apps.  Neither seem to send either of those keys/combinations.

Does anyone know an android app that will send those keystrokes into a Remote Desktop?  I'll also need the <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, & <kbd>F5</kbd> function usage native to the Remote Desktop, not the Android OS.  <kbd>F3</kbd> seems to perform a force close and <kbd>F4</kbd> seems to turn the screen off/on.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find a remote desktop program to do it for you, all I can suggest is to set up an Auto Hot Key Script that will do those combinations upon you doing an action/key combination that the application likes.

If you do want to go down this route, let me know in comments and I will try to write/help you down this route.